# How I can subscribe to conference/seminar/workshop alerts?

Tags: conference, postdocs, seminars, workshop

Can anybody please provide me link from where I can subscribe to alerts for international conferences, seminar,  workshop etc or postdoc positions ? This could be very useful for me as I generally miss important conferences/seminars/workshops.

Comment: That critically depends on your discipline and research area. Typically, there are mailing lists for almost any discipline. For the UK, you can find a lot of mailing lists here: https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?INDEX&X=&Y=, see, for example the allstat mailing list for statistics

Answer (score 3):

There are several sources I get information from:

1. **Mailing list**: See if you can find a mailing list specific to your area. Ask your advisor and colleagues about them.
2. Friends and colleagues in the field.
3. **Word of mouth at other conferences**: Ask participants about their favorite conferences & workshops.
4. **Invitation emails** of various kinds.
5. The academic sub-twitterverse
6. Wiki CFP: http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/

Note that there are many conference/workshops that are not worth going to. And some of them are right out **scams**. I've read a number of horror stories about them (e.g. https://scholarlyoa.com/tag/predatory-conferences/). I suggest you choose carefully.

Comment: WikiCfp is really simple and useful

Comment: WikiCfp: Use with caution. The vast majority of listed conferences in my field is on the sketchy side.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper there seems to be increasing number of hoax conferences everywhere. I no longer look at wikiCFP myself.

Comment: The last link seems to have fallen to bit rot.

Answer (score 1):

Just google for research conference websites you will get lot of them.
I personally use Www. edas.info it sorts all the conferences according to your need e.g area, date wise, region etc

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of such services, for instance:

- http://www.allconferences.com/
- https://www.conferencealert.com/
- https://www.worldconferencealerts.com/
- https://conferencealerts.co.in/
- http://allconferencealert.net/
- https://conferencenext.com/
- [Europe Conference](https://conferenceineurope.net/)

and I am sure you can find many more. I tend to be cautious with those, and trust a little more those maintained by individual, universities and academic associations. If they do not have mailing lists, you can subscribe to services of [website content changes](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-website-change-notification/).

As for post-docs positions, they might be much less centralized.